# Reducing Iterable[Either[A,B]] to Either[A, Iterable[B]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iterable, either

I need to reduce an Iterable[Either[Throwable, String]] to an Either[Throwable, Iterable[String]]. I don't know if this operation is pretty common or not, haven't found nothing on the Iterable trait. So I have written this function:

```
def reduce[A, B](xs: Iterable[Either[A, B]]): Either[A, Iterable[B]] = 
  xs.collectFirst {
    case Left(x) => x
  } match {
    case Some(x) => Left(x)
    case None => Right(xs.collect{case Right(y)=> y})
  }
```

Can anyone help me to find a better way if this one it isn't?

Comment: The transformation you want to achieve is a bit ambiguous. Your input list contains for example half of `Right[String]`s and half of various and heterogeneous `Left[Exception]`s. You want to reduce it to either one exception or list of strings. Which exception should be taken if there were e.g. ten different in the input?

Comment: You are right. I want to consider only the first exception (or any Left value) it will hide other but it is acceptable for my use case.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230999/how-to-reduce-a-seqeithera-b-to-a-eitherseqa-seqb.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This operation is often called *sequencing*, and is available in the standard libraries of some functional languages (such as Haskell). In Scala you can either implement your own, or use an external library like [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/). Suppose we have the following, for example:

```
val xs: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2))
val ys: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Left("1st!"), Left("2nd!"))
```

Now we can write (using Scalaz 7):

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> xs.sequenceU
res0: Either[String,List[Int]] = Right(List(1, 2))

scala> ys.sequenceU
res1: Either[String,List[Int]] = Left(1st!)
```

As desired.

---

As a side note, this operation just requires that the outside container be traversable and that the inside container be an applicative functor. Scalaz also provides a `ValidationNEL` class that's a lot like `Either` and also fits these requirements, but using `sequence` on a list of `ValidationNEL`s collects multiple errors instead of stopping at the first:

```
val zs: List[ValidationNEL[String, Int]] =
  List(1.successNel, "1st".failNel, "2nd".failNel)
```

Now we get:

```
scala> print(zs.sequenceU)
Failure(NonEmptyList(1st, 2nd))
```

You could also use `sequence` on a list of `Option`s, `Promise`s, etc.

Comment: In fact it is very similar to `Future.sequence` in the Akka framework, isn't it?

Comment: @FilippoDeLuca: Yep, exactly, that one's just less generic than Scalaz's.

Comment: I'm not yet able to fully understand scalaz, but I have to give it a try indeed, or better, it has to give a try to me :)

Comment: @FilippoDeLuca: I definitely don't fully understand Scalaz myself! One of the nice things about it is that you don't need to—just pick some starting points and wander around.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like the explicit return and want to eliminate the pattern matching while shortening the code somewhat, here is another version:

```
def reduce[A, B](xs: Iterable[Either[A, B]]): Either[A, Iterable[B]] =
  xs collectFirst {
    case Left(x) => Left(x)
  } getOrElse Right(xs.flatMap(_.right.toOption))
```

Answer (score 2):

I always find `return` statements a bit awkward, but this following works:

```
def reduce[A, B](xs: Iterable[Either[A, B]]): Either[A, Iterable[B]] =
  Right(xs.collect {
    case Left(x) => return Left(x)
    case Right(x) => x
  })
```

Comment: `case Left(x) => return Left(x)` can be shortened to `case l@Left(_) => return l`

Comment: @KimStebel yes I thought that at first, but the `B` type parameter of the resulting `Either` is wrong (it requires `Iterable[B]` but is `B` instead), so the `Left` is a different `Left`.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not using the return statement.

Comment: I think this is a good example of where the use of `return` is appropriate (the dislike of `return` shouldn't become dogma). Process something iteratively but bail early with a return for some exceptional condition. It's like a collecting collectFirst (which despite the name doesn't really collect), which does indeed use return in its implementation