# Scala: Combine Either per the whole List with Either per elements

Tags: scala, validation, error-handling, scala-cats, either

I have a list of Either, which represents error:

```
type ErrorType = List[String]
type FailFast[A] = Either[ErrorType, A]

import cats.syntax.either._
val l = List(1.asRight[ErrorType], 5.asRight[ErrorType])
```

If all of them are right, I want to get a list of [A], in this case - `List[Int]`

If any `Either` is left, I want to combine all errors of all either and return it.

I've found a similar topic at [[How to reduce a Seq[Either[A,B]] to a Either[A,Seq[B]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230999/how-to-reduce-a-seqeithera-b-to-a-eithera-seqb])

But it was quite long ago. For instance, one of the answers offers to use `partitionMap`, which I cannot find at this moment. Probably there is a better, more elegant solution. Example with scala-cats would be great.

How I would like to use it:

```
for {
  listWithEihers <- someFunction
  //if this list contains one or more errors, return Left[List[String]]
  //if everything is fine, convert it to:
  correctItems <- //returns list of List[Int] as right
} yield correctItems
```

Return type of this for-comprehension must be:

```
Either[List[String], List[Int]]
```

Comment: It looks like you want to use [`Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) instead of `Either`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I've used it in cases when I know in advance the number of functions that return Either, I can combine them with Semigroupal.tupleN. But cannot get it how to use it in this context. Number of list elements is unknown.

Comment: Maybe something like `listWithEihers.foldMap(e => Validated.fromEither(e).toValidatedNec)`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, foldMap, what is it? Cannot find it among method of List or Either

Comment: Oh sorry, it is an extension method provided by `import cats.syntax.foldable._` to any `C[_]` like type which have a instance of `Foldable[C]`. The signature is `foldMap[A, B](f: A => B)(implicit M: Monoid[B]): B` Basically it maps the values in the collection and fold them together using a monoid, and the monoid of `Validated` accumulates errors and values.

Comment: You don't want to fold it, you want to `traverse` or `sequence` with `Traverse`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, `Either` is good for fail-fast behavior. For accumulating multiple errors, you probably want something like `Validated`. Moreover:

- List is traversable (has instance of `Traverse`)
- Validated is applicative
- `Validated.fromEither` maps `Either[List[String], X]` to `Validated[List[String], X]`, that's exactly what you need as function in `traverse`.

Therefore, you might try:

- `l.traverse(Validated.fromEither)` if you are OK with a `Validated`
- `l.traverse(Validated.fromEither).toEither` if you really want an `Either` in the end.

Full example with all imports:

```
import cats.data.Validated
import cats.syntax.validated._
import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.Traverse
import scala.util.Either

type ErrorType = List[String]
type FailFast[A] = Either[ErrorType, A]
val l: List[Either[ErrorType, Int]] = List(1.asRight[ErrorType], 5.asRight[ErrorType])

// solution if you want to keep a `Validated`
val validatedList: Validated[ErrorType, List[Int]] =
  l.traverse(Validated.fromEither)

// solution if you want to transform it back to `Either`
val eitherList: Either[ErrorType, List[Int]] =    
  l.traverse(Validated.fromEither).toEither
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Luis mention in the comments, `ValidatedNel` is what you are looking for:

```scala
import cats.data.{ Validated, ValidatedNel }
import cats.implicits._

type ErrorType = String

def combine(listWithEither: List[Either[ErrorType, Int]]):ValidatedNel[ErrorType, List[Int]] =
      listWithEither.foldMap(e => Validated.fromEither(e).map(List(_)).toValidatedNel)

      val l1 = List[Either[ErrorType, Int]](Right(1), Right(2), Right(3))
      val l2 = List[Either[ErrorType, Int]](Left("Incorrect String"), Right(2), Left("Validation error"))

println(combine(l1))
// Displays Valid(List(1, 2, 3))

println(combine(l2))
// Displays Invalid(NonEmptyList(Incorrect String, Validation error))
```

You could transform the final rather back to an `Either` using `.toEither`, but `ValidatedNel` is a better structure to accumulate errors, while `Either` is more suited for `fail fast` erroring.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot to turn the `valid` branch in a **List** too.