# Convert List[Either[A, B]] to Either[List[A], List[B]]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

How to convert `List[Either[String, Int]]` to `Either[List[String], List[Int]]` using a method similar to cats [sequence](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html#a-note-on-sequencing)? For example,  `xs.sequence` in the following code

```
import cats.implicits._
val xs: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Left("error1"), Left("error2"))
xs.sequence
```

returns `Left(error1)` instead of required `Left(List(error1, error2))`.

KevinWrights' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7234561/5205022) suggests

```
val lefts = xs collect {case Left(x) => x }
def rights = xs collect {case Right(x) => x}
if(lefts.isEmpty) Right(rights) else Left(lefts)
```

which does return `Left(List(error1, error2))`, however does cats provide out-of-the-box sequencing which would collect all the lefts?

Comment: Maybe this: `xs.traverse(e => Validated.fromEither(e).toValidatedNec).toEither`? Can not test it right now, so it may have typos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Combine Either per the whole List with Either per elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258434/scala-combine-either-per-the-whole-list-with-either-per-elements)

Comment: @MarioGalic I've already mentioned the proposed duplicate in the (now deleted) comments few hours ago, but then decided that it's not completely the same: the `List(_)` part is still needed, and I wasn't 100% sure whether there is some convenience method that wraps elements into lists automatically. Also, I like the title of your question: it's a seriously good canonical title! So, I didn't close (also because I'm hesitant when closing something as duplicate of a question with my own answer). I upvoted it for the canonical title alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another variation on the same theme (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56260428/2707792)), all imports included:

```
import scala.util.Either
import cats.data.Validated
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._

def collectErrors[A, B](xs: List[Either[A, B]]): Either[List[A], List[B]] = {
  xs.traverse(x => Validated.fromEither(x.left.map(List(_)))).toEither
}
```

If you additionally import `cats.syntax.either._`, then the `toValidated` becomes available, so you can also write:

```
xs.traverse(_.left.map(List(_)).toValidated).toEither
```

and if you additionally replace the `left.map` by `bimap(..., identity)`, you end up with @DmytroMitin's wonderfully concise solution.

Answer (score 4):

This solution doesn't use `cats`, but from Scala 2.13, you can use of [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partitionMap[A1,A2](f:A=%3EEither[A1,A2]):(CC[A1],CC[A2])):

```scala
    def convert[L,R](input: List[Either[L,R]]): Either[List[L], List[R]] = {
      val (left, right) = input.partitionMap(identity)
      if (left.isEmpty) Right(right) else Left(left)
    }

    println(convert(List(Left("error1"), Left("error2"))))
    // Left(List(error1, error2))
    println(convert(List(Right(1), Left("2"), Right(3), Left("4"))))
    // Left(List(2, 4))
    println(convert(List(Right(1), Right(2), Right(3), Right(4))))
    // Right(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
xs.traverse(_.toValidated.bimap(List(_), identity)).toEither

// List(Left("error1"), Left("error2")) => Left(List("error1", "error2"))
// List(Right(10), Right(20))           => Right(List(10, 20))
// List(Right(10), Left("error2"))      => Left(List("error2"))
```

Comment: it seems that we don't even need `toValidated/toEither` as `bimap` is available in `EitherOps` :  `xs.traverse(_.bimap(List(_), identity))`

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko We do need `toValidated`. Otherwise behavior will be different ("`Left(error1)` instead of required `Left(List(error1, error2))`" as OP wrote).

Comment: I think you meant `Left(List(error1))` instead of `Left(List(error1, error2))`. The `List(_)` would still be there, but it would always contain only the first error.