# How to transform F[Either[A, B]] to Either[F[A], F[B]]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

A little bit of background: There is a `.separate` function in cats that allows me to get tuple `(F[A], F[B])` out of `F[Either[A, B]]`. Given that, one can easily construct `Either[F[A], F[B]]` - given we can check `F` for emptiness (a monoid would do?). The code for list could look like this

```
val l: List[Either[_, _]] = ???
l.separate match {
  case (Nil, rights) => Right(rights)
  case (lefts, _) => Left(lefts)
}
```

But this seems like a more general concept but I am not quite sure what that is. It looks kinda similar to `.sequence` but our `G` has two holes. That is, we want a transformation `F[G[A, B]] -> G[F[A], F[B]]`.

Do you happen to know if such concept exists or how to achieve this goal with cats without `pattern matching / if statements / Either.cond`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501107/convert-listeithera-b-to-eitherlista-listb

Comment: You have a `List[Either[Int, String]]` which contains the number 42 and the string "So long and thanks for all the fish". What should the result be?

Comment: BTW this is absolutely not possible for arbitrary types (think `Tree[Either[Int, String]]` or `List[Graph[VertexType, EdgeType]]`.

Comment: you can also play with `swap` depending of what is inside your list and what you want to get. Example: `l.map(_.swap).sequence.swap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try it with a combination of `Alternative` and `Traverse`.

[This special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501107/convert-listeithera-b-to-eitherlista-listb) can be generalized from `List` to an arbitrary `F`:

```
def collectErrors[A, B](xs: List[Either[A, B]]): Either[List[A], List[B]] = {
  xs.traverse(_.left.map(List(_)).toValidated).toEither
}
```

Here is a shopping list of stuff that we need to make it work:

1. We need some kind of replacement for `List(_)`. That's usually `Applicative[F].pure(_)` (or `_.pure[F]`), so we need `Applicative`.
2. We need a `Monoid` on `F[X]` so we can accumulate errors in the left part of `Validated`. Fortunately, there is `MonoidK[F[_]]`, which knows how to generate a `Monoid[F[X]]` for any given `X`
3. The `F[_]` must be traversable so we can get from `F[Validated[F[A], B]]` to `Validated[F[A], F[B]]`, thus we need `Traverse`.

There is a trait `Alternative`, which is a combination of `Applicative` and `MonoidK`. 
Putting it all together gives you:

```
  import scala.util.Either
  import cats._
  import cats.syntax.either._
  import cats.syntax.traverse._
  import cats.syntax.applicative._

  def collectErrors[F[_]: Alternative : Traverse, X, Y](xs: F[Either[X, Y]])
  : Either[F[X], F[Y]] = {
    implicit val mon = MonoidK[F].algebra[X]
    xs.traverse(_.left.map(_.pure[F]).toValidated).toEither
  }
```

This should now work for `List`, `Vector`, `Chain`, etc.