# joinLeft [A1 >: A, B1 >: B, C]... why are type constraint A1 >: A and B1>: B necessary?

Tags: scala

Following the nice answer to this question "[What's the deal with the Either cruft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131076/whats-the-deal-with-all-the-either-cruft?answertab=votes#tab-top)", for Either[+A, +B], joinLeft is defined as

```
joinLeft [A1 >: A, B1 >: B, C] (implicit ev: <:<[A1, Either[C, B1]]):
         Either[C, B1]
```

@Didier said "A1 and B1 are technically necessary, but not critical to the
understanding..."; however, I'm curious about why we can't just have

```
joinLeft[C](implicit ev: <:<[A, Either[C, B]): Either[C, B]
```

---

**EDITED**
I tried to applied the concept of variance to joinLeft. Firstly, the source of joinLeft:

```
abstract class Either[+A, +B]

def joinLeft[A1 >: A, B1 >: B, C](implicit ev: A1 <:< Either[C, B1]):
    Either[C, B1] = this match {
    case Left(a)  => a
    case Right(b) => Right(b)
}
```

I might be wrong but the 2ed case seems easier to me:
`Right(b)` would need to satisfy
`Either[C, B1] >: Either[C, B]`. Because Either is covariant, so `B1 >: B`.

But there's a problem: why we have joinLeft of type `Either[C, B1]` rather than
just `Either[C, B]`? Is it because it's less constrained?

`implicit ev: (<:<[A1, Either[C, B1]])` can only be able to convert from A's
supertype `A1` to A1's supertype `Either[C, B1]`.
I think it's used for `a` in the 1st case. But I feel that A1 isn't necessary.
Can we define joinLeft as such:

```
def joinLeft[B1 >: B, C](implicit ev: A <:< Either[C, B1])
```

? My analysis might be nonsense. Please feel free to correct me.

---

**EDITED**
The answer to my another question [type constraints and reifications regarding to joinLeft of Either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013084/type-constraints-and-reifications-regarding-to-joinleft-of-either) is relevant to this one.

---

**EDITED**

Thanks very much to @sschaef for keeping track on this. 
The relevant discussion can be found here:

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/jFw1Bj9aZxE/pRNgZaLLNbEJ
- https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2401

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the type parameters are covariant ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/util/Either.scala#L70)):

```
abstract class Either[+A, +B]
```

The simplest way to explain variances is with a list:

```
abstract class MList[A]
case class Cons[A](head: A, tail: MList[A]) extends MList[A]
object MNil extends MList[Nothing]
```

If we try to instantiate such a list it will not work:

```
scala> Cons(1, MNil)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : MNil.type
 required: MList[Int]
Note: Nothing <: Int (and MNil.type <: MList[Nothing]), but class MList is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
              Cons(1, MNil)
                      ^
```

As the error message says, the problem is that our type `A` is invariant, this means for a type `B` that is a subtype of type `A` (`B <: A`) it is not valid to say `List[B] <: List[A]`.

We can change that by declaring `A` covariant:

```
abstract class MList[+A]
// rest as before

scala> Cons(1, MNil)
res3: Cons[Int] = Cons(1,MNil$@5ee988c6)
```

Covariance means that the subtype relationship of types is forwarded to the outer type, in our example it means that `MList[Nothing] <: MList[Int]` because `Nothing` is Scalas bottom type and thus a subtype of every possible type.

But now, we have a problem. We can't add methods to our `MList` which expect a parameter of type `A`:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class MList[+A] {
  def Cons(b: A) = new Cons(b, this)
}
case class Cons[A](head: A, tail: MList[A]) extends MList[A]
object MNil extends MList[Nothing]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:11: error: covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type (b: A)Cons[A] of method Cons
         def Cons(b: A) = new Cons(b, this)
             ^
<console>:11: error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value b
         def Cons(b: A) = new Cons(b, this)
                  ^
```

To explain why the compiler rejects this code it is necessary to go a bit deeper into the system. We assume that `List[B] <: List[A]` is always true when `B <: A`. Then the following code would compile:

```
val xs: Array[Any] = Array[Int](18)
xs(0) = "hello"
```

Because `Int <: Any`, it is also true that `Array[Int] <: Array[Any]`. And because `String <: Any` is true too the compiler could translate this code without any problems, but at runtime it would fail because we can't store a `String` inside of an `Array[Int]` (there is no type erasure for arrays on the JVM). Thus, in Scala the assignment of a `Array[Int]` to an `Array[Any]` is not valid, the code is rejected. Nevertheless, for `List` we don't get an error:

```
scala> val xs: List[Any] = List[Int](18)
xs: List[Any] = List(18)
```

The reason for the different behavior is because `List` is covariant while `Array` is not (it is invariant). But why the difference? That's because of the immutable nature of `List`, the elements of a `List` can not be changed. But for `Array` we can change the elements - in other words with variances the programmer can give the compiler the information that elements are mutable or not and that it should care that no one does silly things with our code.

We go back to our `MList` that needs to be fixed. Because it is immutable we can safely declare it as covariant. In fact we need to do it because otherwise we can't use `MNil`. It is not possible to give type parameters to an object, thus in order to avoid type problems later, we need to extend `MList` with the lowest possible type, which is `Nothing`. To fix the problem we need to set a lower bound:

```
abstract class MList[+A] {
  def Cons[B >: A](b: B) = new Cons(b, this)
}
case class Cons[A](head: A, tail: MList[A]) extends MList[A]
object MNil extends MList[Nothing]

scala> MNil Cons 2 Cons 1
res10: Cons[Int] = Cons(1,Cons(2,MNil$@2e6ef76f))
```

`B >: A` is our lower bound and means `A` is a subtype of `B` or `B` is a supertype of `A`. To get a `MList[Int]` when we have a `MList[Nothing]` (which is `MNil`) we need such a lower bound because `Int >: Nothing` and we have `MList[Nothing].Cons[Int].Cons[Int]`.

So, that is the reason why `joinLeft` needs such lower bounds too. In fact, it is true that for `joinLeft` only the second type bound `B1 >: B` is necessary, the other one is not needed because `<:<` already is contravariant in its first type parameter. This means the lower bound on `A` doesn't have any effect (*side note: I opened a pull request that deletes the lower bound on `A` but the change is rejected because it breaks backwards source compatibility and no workaround could be found.*)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. But I'm a bit puzzled by the last example. `Cons(1, Cons(2, MNil))` would work without MList's Cons. Did you mean that if I define a MList.mcons and like to do something like `Cons(1, MNil).mcons(2)`?

Comment: I tried to applied the concept of variance to joinLeft in my question and edited it. But I still couldn't make out. Please feel free to comment on my update.

Comment: @cfchou: I can't think of a use case for the lower bound on `A` at the moment, maybe you are right and it is useless.

Comment: @cfchou: Ok, after thinking about this again, the lower bound on `A` seems unnecessary, because `<:<` is already contravariant in its first type argument. But I may be wrong too...

Comment: @cfchou: I think now I can give a final answer: `A1` is unnecessary for `joinLeft` (see my last paragraph).